# Lead status and custom field history

Tags: leads

does SFDC storage old status values of a Lead and of a custom field? If so, how can I find them? I need to query them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can query the old field values. The history tracking need to enabled for those fields. You can query the LeadHistory object to get the old and new values(it will not store values for all type of fields e.g., long text area). for more info you can check here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_leadhistory.htm. But I should I also tell you that you cannot cover the part this code in the test class because when you insert data in test class, the history object will not be inserted during test execution. But there is a workaround, you will have to supply the test class with live data from your org and make sure that the live data satisfies your criteria.

Hope it helps!

Comment: History tracking seems to keep track of the changes in a field but just stating e.g. "Lead status changed to New". What I need is the actual old value of the Status field in the Lead object so I can query it.

Comment: You can use this query to get the old and new value Select Id, Name, (Select NewValue, Field, oldValue From Histories) From Lead where id = 'leadId'.. You can run the query in developer console and check..

Comment: If you donot want a inner query you can directly query : select newValue, oldValue, field from leadHistory where leadId = 'leadId'

Comment: Kewl.. You can mark it as answer as it can help others as well

Answer (score 1):

Only if you've configured "History Tracking" for those fields, found under Setup > Customize > Leads > Fields. If you enable this feature, it won't backtrack historical changes, only new changes. That means that, in your particular case, you probably won't be able to restore these old values for reporting, but configuring this setting now will help you in the future.